# Is an empty meta refresh tag ignored or equivalent to 0?

Tags: html, page-refresh, http-equiv

I am working on a site where every page has this tag in the `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content=""/>
```

The site's CMS has a `meta` `refresh` field you can set if needed, but it's not set, so this dummy `refresh` tag shows up on every page.

Does the browser ignore this or is it equivalent to a "0" second refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-refresh describes the algorithm to process a meta refresh:

> 2 .If the meta element has no content attribute, or if that attribute's value is the empty string, then abort these steps.